# Can't load a background image using Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I just started programming my first game with Pygame and Pycharm. I'm trying to load the background image in the following code, but an error occurs.

```
import os
import pygame
import pygame.locals
#objects        (classes, functions)



#setup          (run-once code)
worldx = 960
worldy = 720
fps = 40
ani = 4          #animation cycles
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.init()
world = pygame.display.set_mode([worldx,worldy])
current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')
backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'stage.png'))
backdropbox = world.get_rect()
BLUE = (25,25,200)
BLACK = (23,23,23)
WHITE = (254,254,254)

#main loop      (game loop)
```

And this is the error message:

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open C:/Users/Justus/PycharmProjects/Vulcanoreal_game.py\images\stage.png
```

Can somebody please help me? And by the way, my English is not the best, sorry ;)

Comment: Look at the image path. You mixed slashes "/" and "\"

Comment: I'd recommend using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os.path`. It's generally more intuitive for building paths.

Comment: @Dmitry I don't know how to change this. Can you give me the finished code?

Comment: @Dmitry A mix of slashes and backslashes as path delimiters will work without problems  on Windows. The question is: does the path `C:/Users/Justus/PycharmProjects/Vulcanoreal_game.py\images\stage.png` exist?

Comment: Use `os.path.isfile()` to check if the file path is correct before using it. Post the full error message. A part of it is not much of a help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import:

```
import pathlib
```

Your current path should be:

```
current_path = pathlib.Path().absolute()

image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')

backdrop = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'stage.png'))
```

Comment: Did this help you?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the many answers from you. Only backslashes appear in the file path now. But it still doesn't work. I have tried a little bit and now no more errors appear. But the image is still not loaded. I don't get an error message anymore, but the screen that appears is just black and you can't see a picture. Is the picture too big? It is 1,90 MB big and Full HD.

Comment: You are welcome =) I'm not an expert in pygame but I tested this solution and it worked. In main game loop: `world.fill(BLUE)` `world.blit(backdrop, backdropbox)` `pygame.display.flip()` Please try it.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked : ) My motivation is back!